# $P(|x - \mu_1| < |x-\mu_2|)$ for two Gaussian distributions with identical $\sigma^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I've derived a Bayesian decision boundary for a two-category decision problem such that I choose a given category if $P(|x - \mu_1| < |x-\mu_2|)$.  I'm trying to find the probability of this for two Gaussian distributions $N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$,

$$p(x)=\frac{\exp[-\frac{1}{2}](\frac{x-\mu_i}{\sigma})^2]}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$$

I'm a bit rusty on my stats and I'm not quite remembering how I might find $P(|x - \mu_1| < |x-\mu_2|)$, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are your variables independent? If so, then simply by symmetry, your probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for $$ P(|X_1-\mu_1|<|X_2<\mu_2|) $$ where $X_i \sim n(\mu_i,\sigma)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want

$$\text{Pr}\left(\left| x_i-\mu_1\right| < \left| x_i-\mu_2\right|\right)$$

for $i=1$ and $i=2$.

This answer doesn't "point you in the right direction" but gives you the answer from using *Mathematica*:

If $\mu_1=\mu_2$, then the probability is zero for both $i=1$ and $i=2$.  If $\mu_1<\mu_2$, then for $i=1$ the probability is $\Phi \left(\frac{\mu_2-\mu_1}{2 \sigma }\right)$ while for $i=2$ the probability is $1-\Phi \left(\frac{\mu_2-\mu_1}{2 \sigma }\right)$.  If $\mu_1>\mu_2$, then for $i=1$ the probability is $1-\Phi \left(\frac{\mu_2-\mu_1}{2 \sigma }\right)$ and for $i=2$ the probability is $\Phi \left(\frac{\mu_2-\mu_1}{2 \sigma }\right)$ with $\Phi(\cdot)$ being the standard normal cumulative distribution function.

The *Mathematica* code displays as the following:

[image: Image of Mathematica code]

The actual code is

```
(* i = 1 *)
FullSimplify[
 Probability[Abs[x - μ1] < Abs[x - μ2], 
    x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ1, σ],
    Assumptions -> {σ > 0, μ1 ∈ Reals, μ2 ∈ Reals}] /.
   Erf[z_] -> 1 - Erfc[z] /. Erfc[z_] -> 2 Φ[-Sqrt[2] z]]

(* i = 2 *)
FullSimplify[
 Probability[Abs[x - μ1] < Abs[x - μ2], 
    x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ2, σ],
    Assumptions -> {σ > 0, μ1 ∈ Reals, μ2 ∈ Reals}] /.
   Erf[z_] -> 1 - Erfc[z] /. Erfc[z_] -> 2 Φ[-Sqrt[2] z]]
```